# MPI_Comm_split not working with MPI_Bcast

Tags: c++, c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmpi

With following code I am splitting 4 processes in column groups, then broadcasting in same column from diagonal (0,3). Process 0 broadcasts to 2. And 3 should broadcast to 1. But it is not working as expected. Can some one see whats wrong ?

```
0 1
2 3

    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <mpi.h>
    #include <mpi.h>
    using namespace std;
    
    int main(int argc, char **argv){
        MPI_Comm col_comm,row_comm;
        int myrank, size, even, value=0;
        int localRank=0;
        MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
        MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);      
        MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myrank%2, myrank, &col_comm); 
        MPI_Comm_rank (col_comm, &localRank);
            
        if(myrank%3==0){
            value = myrank*5+1;
            MPI_Bcast(&value, 1, MPI_INT, localRank, col_comm);
        }
        
        printf("Rank=%d | LocalRank=%d | Got broadcast value of %d\n", myrank, localRank, value);
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }
```

The Output

```
ubuntu@root:~/matrixmult$ mpirun comtest -np 4
Rank=0 | LocalRank=0 | Got broadcast value of 1
Rank=1 | LocalRank=0 | Got broadcast value of 0
Rank=2 | LocalRank=1 | Got broadcast value of 0
Rank=3 | LocalRank=1 | Got broadcast value of 16
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MPI_Bcast](https://www.mpich.org/static/docs/latest/www3/MPI_Bcast.html)

> Broadcasts a message from the process with rank "root" to all other
> processes of the communicator

is a collective communication routine, **hence it should be called by all the processes in a given communicator**. Therefore, you need to remove the following condition `if(myrank%3==0)` and then you need to adapt the *root* process accordingly, instead of using `localRank`.

In your current code, only the processes with `myrank` 0 and 3 called the `MPI_Bcast` (both belonging to different communicators). So process 0 calls

```
MPI_Bcast(&value, 1, MPI_INT, localRank, col_comm);
```

which basically means that it broadcasted the value to itself. The same happens with process 3. Hence, the output:

```
Rank=0 | LocalRank=0 | Got broadcast value of 1
Rank=1 | LocalRank=0 | Got broadcast value of 0
Rank=2 | LocalRank=1 | Got broadcast value of 0
Rank=3 | LocalRank=1 | Got broadcast value of 16
```

Rank=0 and Rank=3 communicated with themselves, while the other processes where not part of the `MPI_Bcast`. Hence the value of 0 for both of them.

Try the following:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    MPI_Comm col_comm,row_comm;
    int myrank, size, even, value=0;
    int localRank=0;
    MPI_Init (&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myrank);
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);      
    MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, myrank%2, myrank, &col_comm); 
    MPI_Comm_rank (col_comm, &localRank);
     
    if(myrank == 0 || myrank == 3)    
       value = myrank*5+1;
    
    MPI_Bcast(&value, 1, MPI_INT, myrank%2 != 0, col_comm);
    
    printf("Rank=%d | LocalRank=%d | Got broadcast value of %d\n", myrank, localRank, value);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

> Process 0 broadcasts to 2. And 3 should broadcast to 1.

Output:

```
Rank=0 | LocalRank=0 | Got broadcast value of 1
Rank=1 | LocalRank=0 | Got broadcast value of 16
Rank=2 | LocalRank=1 | Got broadcast value of 1
Rank=3 | LocalRank=1 | Got broadcast value of 16
```